# php oracle integration where to begin?

Tags: php, oracle

We have an up and running server with php and mysql. We want to use Oracle db as well as the mysql(for performance issues).

What can be the steps to implement oracle to php? Can you give me a head start on where to begin?

Comment: Our team leader decided that we'll use oracle as well, I'm just a simple coder, I need to learn how to do that so I'm asking this @andrius

Comment: you should have asked google first.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying come implement this for me or I didn't even ask for code snippets. I'm just asking where to start which is a very fine question for someone who have never touched any oracle product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use oci driver for oracle connectivity with php, You can use 2 different way for php & oracle connectivity. First way to enable php_pdo_oci extension and 2nd install php_oci8 or php_oci8_11g depends on oracle version. For the starting purpose you can check you connection with sample code below for php_pdo_oci extension.

```
$tns ='tns:port/dbname';
$db_username = 'username';
$db_password = 'password';

try{
$db = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns,$db_username,$db_password,array(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION => true));
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
die("getConnection: " .$e->getMessage());
}

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT FIELD_NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID=1");
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll start digging from here

Answer (score 0):

If want to use core php you can use [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php)

Else if you can use CodeIgnitor framework which provide ORM support with many database like mysql, oracle, etc...